# Salvar dados de uma pesquisa em uma página

Tags: session

Galera, tenho a seguinte situação: tem uma página simples em PHP onde tenho um filtro de pesquisa que me permite pesquisar por Status, CPF/CNPJ, Razão Social/Nome Completo, Data Inicial e Data Final. Após executar a pesquisa, o sistema me trás no datatable os dados do banco. Até aí tudo bem, o problema está no seguinte: se eu edito ou excluo alguma informação desta tabela, quando retorno para esta mesma página, eu perco as informações de pesquisa e consequentemente é necessário digitar tudo novamente para que eu possa ter novamente aqueles dados. Gostaria de saber se alguém conhece alguma forma de salvar os dados desta pesquisa? Pensei na possibilidade de salvar estes dados de pesquisa dentro de sessions, seria a melhor saída? Se sim, teria como executar o action do form de pesquisa dentro desta mesma página ou teria que sair dela também, chamar uma nova página para gravar os dados na session?

Answer (score 0):

Tenta usar um `setcookie("name","value",time()+$int);` e `$_COOKIE["name"]`
é mais simples acho.